# java : TreeSet Collection and Comparable interface

Tags: java, collections

I have following code :
I am trying to insert Item object in TreeSet and I am not getting desire output.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Item i1=new Item(1,"aa");
        Item i2=new Item(5,"bb");
        Item i3=new Item(10,"dd");
        Item i4=new Item(41,"xx");
        Item i5=new Item(3,"x5");
        TreeSet t=new TreeSet();    
        t.add(i1);
        t.add(i2);
        t.add(i3);
        t.add(i4);
        t.add(i5);
        System.out.println(t);      
    }
}
class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{
    String  nm;
    int price;
    public Item(int n,String nm)
    {
        this.nm=nm;
        price=n;
    }
    public int compareTo(Item i1)
    {
        if(price==i1.price)
            return 0;
        else if(price>=i1.price)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    public String  toString()
    {
        return "\nPrice "+price+" Name : "+nm;
    }    
}
```

Output :

[ Price 1 Name : aa,
Price 5 Name : bb,
Price 10 Name : dd,
Price 41 Name : xx ]

`Item i5=new Item(3,"x5");` is not Inserted why?
Why I can do to insert in TreeSet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't implemented `compareTo()` correctly. Here's an extract from javadoc:

```
Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer,
zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than
the specified object.
```

Your implementation doesn't return `-1` in case price of current object is less than price of object you compare with.

Answer (score 2):

In your `compareTo` method you should have `else return -1;` !

Answer (score 2):

In `compareTo` replace:

```
else
        return 0;
```

with:

```
else
        return -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

A class implementing `Comparable` must comply with the contract: if `a.compareTo(b) < 0` then `b.compareTo(a) > 0`. Yours does not comply.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is in your compareTo method. You have implemented a wrong logic. I have modified your class and tested at my eclipse it giving desired output. look at below code.

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        Item i1=new Item(1,"aa");
        Item i2=new Item(5,"bb");
        Item i3=new Item(10,"dd");
        Item i4=new Item(41,"xx");
        Item i5=new Item(3,"x5");
        TreeSet<Item> t=new TreeSet<Item>();    
        t.add(i1);
        t.add(i2);
        t.add(i3);
        t.add(i4);
        t.add(i5);
        System.out.println(t);      
    }
}
class Item implements Comparable<Item>
{
    String  nm;
    int price;
    public Item(int n,String nm)
    {
        this.nm=nm;
        price=n;
    }
    public int compareTo(Item i1)
    {
        // Objects equal so no need to add 
        if(price==i1.price)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        // Object are greater
        else if(price>i1.price)
        {

            return 1;
        }
        // Object is lower
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public String  toString()
    {
        return "\nPrice "+price+" Name : "+nm;
    }    
}
```